# Major axis regression / Reduced Major axis regression in mathematica

Tags: fitting

By default the function 'LinearModelFit' uses ordinary least squares. I needed some variation in the method to compare the results, such as Major axis regression or Reduced Major axis regression. Could any one please tell me how to perform Major axis regression or Reduced Major axis regression? Can the function 'LinearModelFit' be used with different argument for this purpose?

Please refer to 
http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/regression/Chapter2-Regression-SimpleLinearRegressionAnalysis.pdf
page - 2, Direct regression.
I think mathematica, by default, follow this. I need the results according to Major axis regression / reduced major axis regression; page - 3 & 4.