# How many different methods of least square estimation can be performed in mathematica?

Tags: fitting

Let's take a simple case 
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i$$ 
$$x_i \,\,\,\, y_i$$     are the observed data of independent variable and the dependent variable respectively.     $$\beta_0 \,\,\,\,\beta_1 $$      are estimated by minimizing the sum of vertical distances of the observed data from the fitted line 
$$s\left(\beta_0, \beta_1\right) = \Sigma_i (\epsilon_i)^2 = \Sigma_i (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_i)^2$$
this is known as ordinary least square estimate or direct regression. 
The other methods of parameter estimation consists of 
(i) Inverse regression: sum of horizontal distances of the observed data from the fitted line is minimized 
 
(ii) Major axis regression: sum of perpendicular distances of the observed data from the fitted line is minimized 
 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPerpendicularOffsets.html 
 
(iii) Reduced major axis regression: the sum of the areas of rectangles, defined between the observed data points and the nearest point on the fitted line, is minimized. 
 
etc..
 
For more details please refer to 
http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/regression/Chapter2-Regression-SimpleLinearRegressionAnalysis.pdf  page 2-4. 
LinearModelFit may use ordinary least square estimate by default. Can the other three methods be performed in mathematica? If so how?

Comment: Of course you can develop code to implement any method you wish

Comment: Is there anything readily available in mathematica?

Comment: Not readily available in the sense of a  built in function .  2 is trivially done  by reversing the data. 3 needs nminimize.

Comment: ok let me have a look at nminimize. what about Reduced major axis regression, the last one I mentioned?

Comment: This is definitely more information than provided in your previous question:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170477/major-axis-regression-reduced-major-axis-regression-in-mathematica.  But next time you might want to edit a closed question rather than opening a new one with the same question.

Comment: *this* question is too broad. You want a laundry list of solutions for a bunch of methods?

Comment: No. I just want to know whether there is a shorter way of performing other methods in mathematica or do I have to write extensive code for every single method. BTW Inverse regression can be done trivially for bi-variate model by reversing the data, however same can not be done in multivariate model as there are multiple x's.

Answer (score 5):

Reduced major axis regression:

Example data:

```
SeedRandom[0]
data = Table[  {# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1]], 
      1 + # + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1]]} &@ 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}] , {12}] ;
```

standard linear regression for comparison:

```
fit = LinearModelFit[data, x, x][x]
```

error defined as (positive) area of rectangle between point and nearest point to line:

```
errRMA[m_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, pt_List] := 
      Abs[Times @@ Subtract @@@
      Transpose[{({{1, m}, {m, m^2}}.pt - {m, -1} b)/(1 + m^2), pt}]]
```

note the distance formula can be found from `RegionNearest[InfiniteLine[{{0,b},{1,m+b}}],{p,q}]`

minimize error

```
rmafit = m x + b /. 
  FindMinimum[Total[errRMA[m, b  , #] & /@ data  ] , {m, b}][[2]]
Show[{ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1], 
  Plot[{fit, rmafit }, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}]}]
```

[image]

illustration:

```
nr = RegionNearest[Line[{{0, rmafit /. x -> 0}, {1, rmafit /. x -> 1}}]];
Show[{
  ListPlot[data, 
   Epilog -> ({FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Dashed], 
      Rectangle[#, nr[#]] & /@ data})],
  Plot[rmafit , {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

aside, note that the reduced major axis regression error formulation has degenerate minima. If you fit a line exactly horizontal or vertical then all the rectangles have zero area, hence zero error. For robustness you probably want to do an ordinary linear regression and use those parameters as the initial guess for `FindMinimum`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it in detail.